# Breakpoint Java system code for debugging

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

My Java application has a problem I'm struggling to solve. I need to breakpoint `runWorker`() method of `ThreadPoolExecutor` , but because this is a standard Java class I dont think I can add breakpoints to stop it when I run in my IntelliJ Java tool.

I could view the source in IntelliJ and set a breakpoint but unlike breakpoints in my own code it had no effect.

What is the right approach here ?

Comment: Is it ThreadExecutorPool or  ThreadPoolExecutor ?

Comment: @c0der sorry its ThreadPoolExecutor, corrected question

Comment: Adding a breakpoint to the `ThreadPoolExecutor#runWorker(Worker)` method worked for me using IntelliJ; execution was suspended and was able to step though the code.

Comment: @Slaw thats for confirming it should work, the problem was the attached src was for Java 1.8.1 but I was running as Java 10, when I changed to run as java 1.8.1 it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the attached src was for Java 1.8.1 but I was running as Java 10, when I changed to run as java 1.8.1 it worked.